# How do you modify Excel VBA labels using Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm working on automating a process with powershell for someone that is currently using an Excel sheet that utilizes macros and **form control** objects. I have the process mostly automated so far, but the sheet has a spot where the user has to click a button on the sheet which brings up a folder selection window where they select a folder for output files. The selection gets stored to a **form control label** object rather than in a cell. A macro then runs using the value stored in that label. I have been unable to track down any information on how I can modify the value for that label object through powershell.

Here is the VBA code that assigns the value to the label:

```
Private Sub SelectFolderButton_Click()
'Selects the folder (directory) for output files
Dim fd As FileDialog

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  With fd
    If (-1 = .Show) Then FolderLabel.Caption = .SelectedItems(1)
  End With

End Sub
```

Unfortunately the user doesn't want the vba code to be changed. So I can't modify it to store the value in a cell and then have the macro use the cell instead, which would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Is this  label a Form Control label, an ActiveX label, or a regular textbox (shape)?

Comment: This may help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09e31365-2997-48ff-9e98-b01468ed805c/powershell-and-excels-form-controls?forum=exceldev

Comment: So, you know how to handle the value stored in a cell, but you cannot handle the one stored in a label. Where this label is situated? On the page (Form or ActiveX control) or on a form? Please share the code dealing with the cell value, clarify the issue regarding the label type and maybe we can better help you adapting it according to the described need.

Comment: Do they really do not want VBA code changed? What's stopping you from making a new VBA module that provides the desired functionality and invoking it instead?

Comment: @BigBen I have updated my question. It is a Form Control label.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have updated my question, It is a Form Control label that exists on the sheet.

Comment: if ``$wB` would be the workbook object and the label is a shape of the worksheet "testSheet" you can try this in order to obtain the label value: `$wB.Worksheets.item("testSheet").Shapes.item("lblTest").Oleformat.Object.Object.Caption`.

Comment: @FaneDuru That worked perfectly. If you want to turn your comment into an answer then I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$wB` would be the workbook object and the label `"lblTest"` is a Form Control shape of the worksheet `"testSheet"` you can try this in order to obtain the label value:

`$wB.Worksheets.item("testSheet").Shapes.item("lblTest").Oleformat.Object.Object.Caption`